# Pandas - Fill in missing values choosing values from a normal distribution

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

The code below will generate only *one* value of a normal distribution, and fill in all the missing values with this same value:

```
helper_df = df.dropna()
df = df.fillna(numpy.random.normal(loc=helper_df.mean(), scale=numpy.std(helper_df)))
```

What can we do to generate a value for each missing value?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a series with normal values. You should extract the index of the Nan values in the column you are working on.

df: your dataframe

col: the col containing Nan values

```
index = df[df.col.isna()].index
value = np.random.normal(loc=data.col.mean(), scale=data.col.std(), size=data.Age.isna().sum())

data.col.fillna(pd.Series(value, index=index), inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a series of random variables with the same length as your dataframe, then apply fillna:

```
df.fillna(pd.Series([np.random.normal() for x in range(len(df))]))
```

If a value in a row is not missing, fillna just ignores it.